# LUKS-encrypted text file is garbled

Tags: data-recovery, luks

I have a USB disk encrypted with [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup).  Immediately after mounting the disk today, I find that a recently edited text file contains seemingly random characters.  All other files that I have checked, and the directory hierarchy, appear to be normal.

What can cause this, and can such a file be recovered?

I do have a recent backup of the entire disk, and a recent version of the text file is committed to a Git archive.  I am, however, interested in a fix -- as well as preventative guidance.

Comment: This would likely be basic filesystem corruption, and not LUKS related. LUKS operates at the block device level, it has no concept of files (it is possible for a small section of the block device to be corrupt due to LUKS, but highly unlikely). As such, I'd run filesystem repair tools and see what they come up with.

Comment: Do a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: Minor, usually recoverable, file-system corruption has become a recurring problem -- seemingly correlated with the suspend mode of my laptop (and even if I 'sync' before going to sleep).  I wonder if memory corruption is a known problem in these circumstances -- I haven't yet tried to test for memory corruption across a sleep.  I wonder if there is a simple way to flush all caches and reload from disk.

Comment: I have had some success with fixing seemingly broken file systems (directories reported empty after a suspend) by running the memory test posted below -- presumably as a way of flushing disk caches.  Not sure if this is related to the original reported problem (a garbled file), which has only occurred one time (knock-on-wood).  A hypothesis about the garbled file is that I saved the file to a confused file system and this resulted in the corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-and-dirty memory test, written in 'C'.  If the disk corruption is due to a memory failure, this might be an easy way to check for that.

Be careful, **this will lock up your computer** (with virtual memory thrashing) if you attempt to test significantly more memory than is readily available.

```
time { make -s CFLAGS="-Wall -Werror -std=c99" mymemtest && free -m && ./mymemtest && free -m && echo "PASS" || echo "FAIL" ; }
```

---

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdint.h>
   #include <assert.h>

int main()
   {
   fprintf(stderr,"\n");
   fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(int)=%ld, sizeof(void*)=%ld\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(void*) );

   double TESTSIZE = 2.2; // amount of memory to test in GB
   uint64_t K=1024; // used to define a GB

   typedef uint64_t T;
   uint64_t sizebytes=TESTSIZE*K*K*K;
   uint64_t size = sizebytes/sizeof(T);
   T * a = malloc(sizebytes);
   assert( a != NULL );
   fprintf(stderr,"sizebytes=%ld, size=%ld, chunk size=%ld, test size=%g GB\n", sizebytes, size, sizeof(T), sizebytes/(double)(K*K*K) );

   fprintf(stderr,"writing...\n");  for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) a[i] = i;
   fprintf(stderr,"checking...\n"); for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) assert( a[i] == (T)i );

   fprintf(stderr,"writing...\n");  for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) a[i] = 0;
   fprintf(stderr,"checking...\n"); for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) assert( a[i] == (T)0 );

   fprintf(stderr,"writing...\n");  for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) a[i] = -1;
   fprintf(stderr,"checking...\n"); for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) assert( a[i] == (T)-1 );

   fprintf(stderr,"writing...\n");  for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) a[i] = 0x5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5AUL;
   fprintf(stderr,"checking...\n"); for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) assert( a[i] == (T)0x5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5AUL );

   fprintf(stderr,"writing...\n");  for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) a[i] = 0xA5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5UL;
   fprintf(stderr,"checking...\n"); for ( uint64_t i=0; i<size; i++ ) assert( a[i] == (T)0xA5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5UL );

   free(a);
   fprintf(stderr,"\n");
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: This test always passes for me.

Answer (score 0):

### file system confusion after suspend (Ubuntu 13.10)

I have isolated recurring file system problems to correlate with suspending my laptop while the LUKS-encrypted USB disk is mounted.  Commonly, it thinks that whatever directory I had open in a terminal is now empty after resuming from suspend.  It seems likely that saving a file to such a directory could result in corruption (but this has only happened once).  My typical solution is to unmount the disk before suspending, but sometimes I forget to do this.

I have found that [purging the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336215/86967) fixes the file system after resume:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

It might still be wise to run `sync` before suspending...

Comment: scary if true... you should investigate further how/why that happens.

Comment: Update: Purging the cache seems to help, but *is not a complete solution*.

Comment: Fingers crossed, but I have not observed this problem since upgrading Ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS.

Comment: ...Looks like 14.04 LTS has problems too.

Comment: My current method of dealing with this is to use the Disks utility to "Unmount the filesystem" without locking the encrypted device.  Then I can remount with one click -- not requiring the password.

Comment: I've been running 14.04.1 for a while and had completely forgotten about this issue.  However, I think the reason is that I just quit doing the suspend thing and leave the machine running 24/7.  On the plus side, I don't have disk corruption.  On the minus side, my laptop case has become warped from the constant heat.